# VBA Type Mismatch Error With Range.Value and Range.Row

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I have the following VBA code and it seems to work partially? Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesnt. I am getting a type mismatch error on the "If Len(c.Value) > 30 And c.Row <> 1" Then line. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
Sub GSSLength()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long

    j = 0

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    
        If ws.Name Like "BOM" Then        
            For Each c In ws.Range("A2:R10000")
                If Len(c.Value) > 30 And c.Row <> 1 Then        
                    ws.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3            
                    j = j + 1                
                End If        
             Next c    
        End If
    Next ws

    If j > 0 Then
        MsgBox j & " errors found where the length of cell is longer than 30 characthers, please correct in columns that are red."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of `c` when it fails?

Comment: Most likely there is an error within the cell that fails, e.g. division by zero or sth else

Comment: `c.Row <> 1` will always be `True` by the way, if you're looping over `ws.Range("A2:R10000")`.

Comment: `c` is already referencing the row and column as well so you could consolidate `ws.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3` to `c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this isn't your final code..? The range you've specified will never have `Row = 1` and you're using `"BOM"` in a `Like` statement that seems unnecessary. Maybe you've put this in just for this question.

Ignoring those oddities, you've probably got a cell in that range that contains an error. You can trap these out like so:

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "BOM" Then
        For Each c In ws.Range("A2:R10000")
            
            If Not (IsError(c)) Then

                If Len(c.Value) > 30 And c.Row <> 1 Then
                    ws.Cells(c.Row, c.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
         Next c
    End If
Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips, I just noticed that I had an error in my cells where it was a number format instead of a string, and the LEN function was throwing an error there.